# Service restarts automatically after it is manually stopped

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have created a windows service in C#.NET that is continuously running. Now when i stop it from the services.msc initially it shows that it has been stopped but after some time when i refresh the services.msc it shows as started again. I also checked in the task manager at the same time, i see that the exe of my application gets killed but starts on its own again.

Please help.

Comment: How do you handle onstop in your code?

Comment: Theoretically it shouldn't happen. Then again we don't know what's going on in `OnStop` event. Can you try creating a simple 'Hello World' service and compare the results?

Comment: well i am not doing anything on the onstop event right now.

Comment: What if you change startup type to manual? Please post some code perhaps

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look into the properties of your service, there is a tab called Recovery. Maybe there is something configured on this page which automatically restarts the service.

Maybe you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out a little more about who starts your service?

Comment: Where do i look for the tab called Recovery that you are talking about. Its not present in the properties of the Service that i have created.

Comment: @Snowill Start->Control Panel->Admin. Services->Services.

Right click on a specific service, click Properties and one of the tabs at the top should say Recovery.

Comment: It says "Take no action" for all three types of failures specified.

Comment: I tried creating a sample Windows service in C# and still i am facing the same issue. When i start the service from 'Services' it starts fine but when i try to stop it manually from 'Services' it stops but starts up again immediately.

Comment: I think recovery would only apply if the service was stopping unexpectedly (i.e. crashing). Manually stopping the process is normal. All I can think is that another process is asking to have the service started again.

Comment: Well, this helped me, I had the recovery option set to "on first stop: restart service" which even went through my disabling of the service. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this was something to do with the operating system. I deployed my service on Win2k3 and it worked just fine. It started perfectly and stopped when i stopped it from Services.msc. I was trying to deploy the service on WinXP earlier. Please let me know if anyone else has faced such an issue.